# How to show the information for the telephone and the website and URL on google map by using InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using the sample code of google map API as below, I am trying to make my google map application. But, when I search the restaurant and click the marker on the map, I can't see the information for telephone, website and can't get access to the url. What is the solution for showing the information?

Here is the sample code I referred to 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch?hl=ja

Here is the code I am writing.
https://github.com/takeyan1004/javascript-application/blob/master/grf1218.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of the method textSearch() hasn't the telephone, website or url of a place, you need to make other call to getDetails(place_id) to get that data.

Example:

```
  var places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  places.getDetails({placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id},
      function(place, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          return;
        }
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        //place object has the information about phone, webste...  
        buildIWContent(place);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Solved!